# What would this printf conversion do?

Tags: c, printf

"%4.3d"

I know that %.3 would make it only a 3 number integer, but how would %4.3d affect the number as a whole?

Edit: Yes I have tried writing a program to do this. I just did not understand the output.

Comment: try it and see what happens!

Comment: Have you tried this in a program yet? This is a very thorough guide for printf: http://www.cypress.com/?docID=41924

Comment: What would the act of reading the documentation (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.3` is the precision specifier.  This will cause the integer value to be padded with leading zeros if it's less than 3 digits.

The leading `4` is the width.  This forces it to print at least 4 characters.

If you fed this 42, it would print `042` (with a leading space).

Comment: Thank you for actually answering the question instead of just telling me to test. Of course I would test before posting on stackoverflow.